# choose the function to call at runtime in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

it is a C++ class with 5 objects and 25 functions . at run time i want to pass the object and name of the function as parameters and make the object passed call the specified method .

it is like

```
void actionToBetaken(object,string method_name)
 {
       object.method_name();
 }
```

how it is possible in C++ ?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing that?

Comment: You can't do that directly. That's called reflection and C++ doesn't support that. You need to map strings to method pointers somewhere.

Comment: You know, I look at this and think, this isn't a real C++ question... the syntax is wrong too.

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: The problem is... i have a class with 25 functions and 5 objects for that class. at runtime i ll tell the program ,which object? and which method to call with that object ?

Comment: @user1462684 : No, that's what you think might be a solution. What _problem_ are you trying to solve? Why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is normally done with function pointers:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void f(T &object, U (T::*method)())
{
   (object.*method)();
}
```

This assumes the method takes no arguments. You can pass the method with arguments by doing:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
void f(T &object, U (T::*method)(Args...), Args&&... args)
{
   (object.*method)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    T t;

    f(t, &T::f, 5); // calls t.f(5)
}
```

You can also use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) or [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) for this kind of functionality.

Comment: when the funtion f is called , i need call it as f<actualtype,actualtype>(t,&T::_function_name) ?

Comment: @user1462684 No, you simply call it as I have here. You don't *have* to supply the template arguments, though you can.

Comment: http://chopapp.com/#az1i3xai this code did not worked ...

Comment: @user1462684 You got the syntax wrong, it should be `T (U::*x)()` not `T (U::*x()))`. See the new code [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yc7Hy$2462)